# Why do I keep getting a NPE when I try stub any jdbcTemplate methods while testing a Spring Boot service?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jdbc, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a Spring Boot service method using JUnit 4 and Mockito. For some reason the test fails with a NPE whenever a jdbcTemplate call is made.  I mocked NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and injected the mock NamedParameterJdbcTemplate into the service I'm testing.  I've tried many things including:

- using a different testRunner,
- stubbing the method where JDBCTemplate is being called using a spy on the service being tested.
- And a few more ideas I got from googleing that I can't think of right now...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here, or how I can go about resolving this?

I need to somehow stub jdbcTemplate.jdbcOperations.update and jdbcTemplate.jdbcOperations.query

my code:

test class:

```
package com.cc.ff.vb.service

import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.doNothing
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.whenever
import com.cc.ff.vb.AppConfigProps
import com.cc.ff.vb.controller.StartSessionResponseDTO
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.BDDMockito.given
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner

@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
class  VBServiceTests {

      val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate = mock()

     val nuanceService: NuanceService = mock()

    val appconfigProps: AppConfigProps = mock()

    val eventService: EventServiceImp = mock()

    val audioTrimService: AudioTrimService = mock()

    val vbNuanceStagingDeletionsService: VbNuanceStagingDeletionsService = mock()

    val vbService: VbServiceImp  = VbServiceImp(jdbcTemplate, nuanceService, appconfigProps, eventService, audioTrimService, vbNuanceStagingDeletionsService)


    val vbServiceSpy: VbServiceImp = Mockito.spy(vbService)

@Before
fun setup() {
    initMocks(this)
}

    @Test
    fun `startSession when method is called with valid input a StartSessionDTO is returned`() {
        val msisdn = "0821234567"
        val origConnID = "o123"
        val sessionId = "0821234567"
        val ip = "127.0.0.1"
        val txID = "1234-5678"
        val configSetName = "asdfgf"

        whenever(vbServiceSpy.generateTxID()).thenReturn(txID)
        whenever(vbServiceSpy.sessionStatus(msisdn)).thenReturn(SessionStatus(msisdn, origConnID, sessionId, ip))

        whenever(jdbcTemplate.jdbcOperations.query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Array<Any>::class.java), Mockito.any(ResultSetExtractor::class.java))).thenReturn(SessionStatus(msisdn, origConnID, sessionId, ip))

        given(nuanceService.isSessionValid(txID, msisdn, sessionId, ip, configSetName)).willReturn(true)
        given(nuanceService.startSession(NuanceStartSessionReqDto(txID, msisdn, ip, configSetName))).willReturn(NuanceStartSessionRespDto(txID, sessionId, ip))

        Assert.assertEquals(StartSessionResponseDTO(msisdn), vbService.startSession(msisdn, origConnID, configSetName))
    }

}
```

The method I am testing and all called methods in the same class:

```
@Transactional
    override fun startSession(msisdn: String, origConnID: String, configSetName: String): StartSessionResponseDTO {
        val txId = generateTxID()
        val ss = sessionStatus(msisdn)

        eventService.logEvent(EventType.StartSessionRequest, txId, msisdn, hashMapOf("extTxId" to origConnID))

        if (ss == null) {
            throw ApplicationException(type = ApplicationException.Type.client_error, message = "Concurrent Access Detected: ${msisdn}")
        } else {
            if (ss.sessionId == null || ss.ip == null) {
                //create new Nuance session
                nuanceService.startSession(NuanceStartSessionReqDto(txId, msisdn, configSetName = configSetName)).let {
                    updateSession(msisdn = msisdn, sessionId = it.sessionId, ip = it.ip, origConnID = origConnID)
                }
            } else {
                //check if the sessionId is still valid
                if (!nuanceService.isSessionValid(txId = txId, msisdn = msisdn, sessionId = ss.sessionId, host = ss.ip, configSetName = configSetName)) {
                    nuanceService.startSession(NuanceStartSessionReqDto(txId, msisdn, configSetName = configSetName)).let {
                        updateSession(msisdn = msisdn, sessionId = it.sessionId, ip = it.ip, origConnID = origConnID)
                    }
                }

                if (origConnID == ss.origConnID) {
                    //update the conn id
                    updateSessionConnId(msisdn, origConnID)
                }
            }
        }

        eventService.logEvent(type = EventType.StartSessionResponse, txId = txId, msisdn = msisdn)
        return StartSessionResponseDTO(msisdn)
    }

fun generateTxID(): String {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }

fun sessionStatus(msisdn: String): SessionStatus? {
            ensureSessionKey(msisdn)

            return try {
                jdbcTemplate.jdbcOperations.query("""select msisdn, session_id, ip, ext_tx_id from session_id_map where msisdn = ? for update """, arrayOf(msisdn), ResultSetExtractor { rs ->
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        SessionStatus(msisdn = msisdn,
                                sessionId = rs.getString(2),
                                ip = rs.getString(3),
                                origConnID = rs.getString(4))
                    } else {
                        null
                    }

fun ensureSessionKey(msisdn: String) {
            jdbcTemplate.jdbcOperations.update("""
            merge into SESSION_ID_MAP a
            using (select ? msisdn from dual) b on (a.MSISDN = b.MSISDN)
            when not matched then insert (a.MSISDN) values (?)""") { ps ->
                ps.setString(1, msisdn)
                ps.setString(2, msisdn)
            }
        }
```

my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cc.ff.vb.service.VbServiceImp.ensureSessionKey(VbServiceImp.kt:632)
    at com.cc.ff.vb.service.VbServiceImp.sessionStatus(VbServiceImp.kt:612)
    at com.cc.ff.vb.service.VBServiceTests.startSession when method is called with valid input a StartSessionDTO is returned(VBServiceTests.kt:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hide the JdbcTemplate inside a DAO service/repository, and mock that repository instead. Trying to mock the exact behaviour of JdbcTemplate is asking for trouble. Then, if you want to test your service/repository, use something like Testcontainers to test against a real database.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thanks. I figured out that my spy stubs (where I tried to stub the methods where jdbcTemplate was used) wasn't working, actual methods were called as a result of using Mockito.whenever().then() instead of doReturn().whenever()

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out the first issue where I got the NPE when I stubbed a method of the service spy (which lead to me trying to stub jdbcTemplate), was a result of not using the correct Mockito method.

After lots of reading up/googling I discovered that spies should be stubbed with doReturn().whenever() and not whenever().thenReturn() where the latter approach would call the actual service methods instead of stubbing the methods.

My working test method now looks like this:

```
@Test
fun `startSession when method is called with valid input a StartSessionDTO is returned`() {
    val msisdn = "0821234567"
    val origConnID = "o123"
    val sessionId = "0821234567"
    val ip = "127.0.0.1"
    val txID = "1234-5678"       
    val configSetName = "LoIvrPhraIvrHdr"

    doNothing().whenever(vbServiceSpy).ensureSessionKey(msisdn)
    doNothing().whenever(vbServiceSpy).updateSession(msisdn, origConnID, sessionId, ip)
    doReturn(txID).whenever(vbServiceSpy).generateTxID()
    doReturn(SessionStatus(msisdn, origConnID, sessionId, ip)).whenever(vbServiceSpy).sessionStatus(msisdn)        

    given(nuanceService.isSessionValid(txID, msisdn, sessionId, ip, configSetName)).willReturn(true)
    given(nuanceService.startSession(NuanceStartSessionReqDto(txID, msisdn, ip, configSetName))).willReturn(NuanceStartSessionRespDto(txID, sessionId, ip))

    Assert.assertEquals(StartSessionResponseDTO(msisdn), vbServiceSpy.startSession(msisdn, origConnID, configSetName))
}
```